Usage of PlanningListVariable
I have a domain where I am trying to optimize the number of fuel trucks at a project site.  A project has a 'requirement' for x amount of fuel a day.  A fuel truck can deliver y amount a fuel.  There can be 1..N fuel trucks available on a given site at one time.  The sum of of the truck capacity should meet or exceed the project capacity.  I'm putting aside the problem of actually routing trucks (vehicle routing problem) and focus on the fuel capacity for now.
I've modeled my current solution after the class scheduling soltuion.  I have a Fuel Schedule, Shift(with @PlanningVariable -> Truck) and Fuel trucks. I have some basic constraints in place and working. However, this is all based off of assigning 1 fuel truck per shift.  Where I'm stuck is how to extend the solution to have n number of potential fuel trucks, and a constraint indicating the sum of fuel truck capacity has to be >= project requirements.
After reading the documentation it seems like I should be using a PlanningListVariable instead of a singular @PlanningVariable on my Shift.  Is there a sample available similar to this?  Any tips on how to proceed would be appreciated.
